# Kafka over ssl: does not have listener with name `ListenerName(SSL)’

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I try to configure my Kafka brokers to work under ssl. I have the following configuration in all brokers:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092, SSL://0.0.0.0:9093
advertised.host.name=my_host_ip
port=9092
ssl.truststore.location=/opt/kafka/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.keystore.location=/opt/kafka/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.key.password=123456
ssl.keystore.password=123456
ssl.truststore.password=123456
```

And some other definitions which are not related to my ssl configuration.

In the client configuration I have the following:

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/opt/kafka_2.12-0.10.2.0/config/ssl/kafka/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=123456
```

With port 9092 (no ssl) everything works well, but when I try to use port 9093 - I got the following error, and I can't post message to the Kafka topic:

```
2017-04-25T16:59:19.945801000Z [2017-04-25 16:59:19,857] ERROR [KafkaApi-2] Error when handling request {topics=null} (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
2017-04-25T16:59:19.945991000Z kafka.common.BrokerEndPointNotAvailableException: Broker `2` does not have listener with name `ListenerName(SSL)’
```

I have ssl connection between the machines (checked with openssl)

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're exposing port 9092, but your SSL is configured to listen to 9093. Also, if I remember correctly, `advertised.host.name` is a deprecated parameter in kafka 0.10.x

I'll suggest commenting out `advertised.host.name=my_host_ip` and `port=9092` and putting `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<ip>:9092, SSL://<ip>:9093`